# What methods are available for complex user input?

Tags: interactive, read

I am experimenting with writing a plugin which requires quite a bit of user input, its a front end to an api.

A typical request will have 4 required inputs and many optional inputs, obviously I can use interactive how ever that's less than ideal because you would have to hit enter on all the optional's to complete the interaction.

What other options do I have perhaps a buffer with input fields would be an option ? not sure what I would search for to achieve that ? or what are my other options ?

Comment: Take a look at the org-export interface, or magit, for interesting examples of UI that allow the user to select a bunch of options.

Comment: The question is too broad. It encourages opinion-based answers. This site encourages specific how-to Q&A.